# Tomcat 7 cannot deploy application because of java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat 7 application that cannot be deployed, cause of this error:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/canje]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringMana$
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:77)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5502)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Apr 05, 2019 10:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app.war
```

May be due to some version problem?

These are the versions in my server:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Oct 10 2018 11:13:44
Server number:  7.0.52.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.13.0-161-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_181-b01
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Any help, please?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

if you are using springboot, maybe conflict between embeded tomcat and your tomcat make this error.
you should exclude tomcat from springboot.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: I have see pom.xml file and that configuration does not exist. The strange thing is that a server, where the application works, has tomcat 7.0.70 and the application is embedding 8.5. The server where it sends that error, has Tomcat 7.0.59.